# Repeated rebuild of right-click menu throws error

Tags: vba, ms-access, drop-down-menu, right-click

I have an Access application that was originally built in Access 2000. Several textboxes and comboboxes use custom right-click menus to call filter routines. The RC menus are built in code, and some are quite extensive - hundreds of items, nested up to four levels deep.

When data in a field changes, I need to rebuild the menu for that field, because the menus filter on the database's actual contents.

In 2000, it all worked well, but in newer versions, repeated rebuilds throw an error.

The relevant part of the code is here:

```
    Dim rst0 As DAO.Recordset, rst1 As DAO.Recordset, rst2 As DAO.Recordset, rst3 As DAO.Recordset, qdf0 As DAO.QueryDef, qdf1 As DAO.QueryDef, qdf2 As DAO.QueryDef, AEp As CommandBarPopup, AEp1 As CommandBarPopup, AEp2 As CommandBarPopup, aec As CommandBarButton
    On Error GoTo ErrHndlr
    With Application.CommandBars("RCDatum")
        Do Until .Controls.count = 0
            If .Controls.count Then .Controls(1).Delete
        Loop
        Set rst0 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("RCDatumDekady").OpenRecordset(acReadOnly)
        Set qdf0 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("RCDatumRok")
        Set qdf1 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("RCDatumRokMesic")
        Set qdf2 = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("RCDatumRokMesicDen")
        Do
            qdf0.Parameters("LoRok") = rst0.Fields("Dekada")
            qdf0.Parameters("HiRok") = rst0.Fields("Dekada") + 9
            Set rst1 = qdf0.OpenRecordset(acReadOnly)
            Set AEp = .Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
```

The last line is where it bombs with the error "Unable to add control", but not always. It runs several times, but after about four or five rebuilds, it suddenly starts throwing an error on that line. Shutting it down, doing a C & R and retrying makes it work again, and again several times okay, then starts bombing.

I sort of suspect I'm abusing the RC system, that it was intended for a few items, more or less permanantly left in place, not such intensive build/rebuild activity with so many items, but I've not found any documentation on the subject, or anyone who claims to have experience with it.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue regarding your specific issue, but perhaps _Dale Fye's_ [Access Shortcut Tool](http://dev-soln.com/access-shortcut-right-click-tool/) or the articles linked to at that page could bring a hint.

Comment: Interesting add-in. I tried installing and using it, and it does fine, but it doesn't list any of my right-click menus. Those must be stored someplace else, and I remember that the original user interface for building them had them stored in a different location. Thanks for the tip, though - I'm going to write him directly and ask about my problem. Maybe he'll be willing to share some tips.

Comment: OK. Go ahead. Dale is usually very responsive.

Comment: No response from Dale, here or elsewhere, but I did get a response from someone else in another forum. He helped me puzzle through the process, and I think I have a plan - mostly, to not rebuild the menus, but to write more intelligent code that will make only the minimum necessary changes. I should have done it that way right from the start, but I was fairly new to Access when I first made this, and happy that I got it to work at all. Now I can do a better job, and that should avoid the problems of doing massive rebuilds.

Comment: Oh. Dale may be busy. But glad you managed.